# Alternativa más corta a "lanzamiento"

Tags: vocabulario-técnico

Hay alguna alternativa a "lanzamiento" en la frase "oferta lanzamiento"? Colocada en dos líneas, la extensión de cada palabra queda muy descompensada, casi el doble de caracteres.

Oferta

Lanzamiento

Los sinónimos que aparecen en las búsquedas son acerca de la acción *lanzar un objeto*, no una oferta. Y las que se me ocurren son bastante poco explícitas con la acción comercial: "oferta inicio".

Comment: El punto es que "lanzamiento" es la palabra que se usa en marketing. Se me ocurren frases cercanas pero que pueden tener otra connotación o campo léxico de uso, como "oferta (de) estreno" u "oferta inaugural".

Comment: Es exactamente lo que me pasa, por eso puse la pregunta a ver si surge algo. En inglés me iría perfecto "Launch Offer" :-/

Comment: ¿[tirada](https://www.wordreference.com/sinonimos/lanzamiento)?

Answer (score 2):

No es una traducción exacta, pero si el problema es tipográfico/diseño yo jugaría con la palabra Novedad

Oferta

¡Novedad!

Comment: Está bien como opción, pero es un poco complicado en mi caso. Se trata de un grupo de productos de una nueva marca englobados como *Novedad* con precios de *Lanzamiento*. Creo estar seguro que existe otra palabra.

Answer (score 1):

Me dedico al marketing y a la publicidad.

Personalmente utilizaría la expresión "Promoción" u "Oferta de Promoción", la preposición "de" te permite jugar con el espacio en varios contextos, depende de la creatividad del diseñador, pero no tienes que tener problemas.

- También es posible utilizar la palabra "Promocional" u "Oferta Promocional" si deseas obviar la preposición "de" y superponerlas a partir de las dos "o" "Oferta - PrOmocional".
- En este sentido, puedes utilizar estas palabras, "Producto Promocional" y utilizar las palabras PrOducto - PrOmocional" con la "O" mayuscula, para ubicarlas gráficamente mejor.
- Por último, si tu empresa es arriesgada y utiliza habitualmente canales de promoción de productos similares cada cierto tiempo o de forma periódica, utilizar las palabras "propro"/"PrO-PrO" con un determinado color para que sea más visible, y a vuestro cliente objetivo le sea más fácil identificar. El cliente, cuando utilicéis varias veces la palabra "pro-pro"/"Producto Promocional" junto con un color indicado, y la hagáis exclusiva, sabrá siempre que es un producto vuestro y nuevo, con una oferta de lanzamiento y estará por tanto en una mejor posición a la hora de recordar y reconocer.

Espero te haya servido. Un saludo.
Diego

Answer (score 1):

El equivalente de `launch` que buscas para los nuevos productos está bien expresado con `lanzamiento`.

Ahora, se me ocurre que `inicio` es quizás un término equiparable a tu idea, promocionando un precio diferencial en la salida de una nueva linea al mercado.

Por lo tanto, si lo decisivo en este caso es la económía de espacio, podrías probar con:

> **Oferta Inicio** 
> (*de apenas un carácter más que* 
>  `Launch Offer`)

Si la preocupación pasa por la asimetría del largo de la expresión en dos lineas, quizás, en lugar de "oferta", a lo mejor funcione:

> **Promoción** 
> **Lanzamiento**

Answer (score 0):

"Lanzamiento" es francamente la mejor opción. Lo que yo haría para compensar visualmente la extensión sería:

OFERTA **DE**

LANZAMIENTO

Answer (score 0):

¿Y qué tal estas opciones?

- **¡Oferta especial!**
- **¡Super Oferta!**

Si las escribes en formato vertical ---que parece que es el que necesitas--- en ambos casos las palabras aparecerían bien alineadas.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Es un precio especial por la introducción al mercado de un producto determinado. No tiene relación con una "oferta especial" o "super oferta", etiquetas que utilizamos en las ocasiones pertinentes.